# Conditional probability and a normal distribution

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Apologies as I have never studied statistics at a high enough level to be sure that I am using some vocabulary correctly.

Let's suppose I draw some $\mu_{1} \dots \mu_{n}$ from a normal distribution $N(0,1)$.  I do not see the values of $\mu_{k}$.  They are hidden and fixed.

And I consider normal distributions $N(\mu_{k} , \sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is a universal constant.

The observational data I have is I make a draw a number of observations $X_{i,k} \sim N(\mu_{k} , \sigma)$ and am given observational data of the form $X_{i,k} > X_{i,k'}$.

So it makes sense to talk about $\mu_{k}$ as having a conditional probability distribution because I will have some observational data which constrains the values I can expect $\mu_{k}$ to take on.  I will take $E[\mu_{k}]$ to mean the expected value of $\mu_{k}$ with respect to this probability distribution.

> How do I go about computing $E[\mu_{k}]$?

For instance, I tried working out the case $n = 2$ and one observation $X_{1,1} > X_{1,2}$ as follows:

The probability that $X_{i,1} > X_{i,2}$ is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left( \frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{2\sigma} \right)$ (which follows since the 2-D normal distribution is rotationally symmetrical).

So the expected value of $\mu_1-\mu_2$ is:

$$\int_{\mathbb R} ( \mu_1 - \mu_2 ) \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left( \frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{2\sigma} \right)\right) \exp(-(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2/4) d ( \mu_1 - \mu_2 )$$

Which after some integration by parts reduces to something like $2(1+\sigma^{2})^{-1/2}$ (although I probably made an error in multiplication).

I figure this is a general enough problem that I should be able to look for a solution in a textbook.  Is there a good resource (i.e. a textbook) that I can look to for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "data in form $X_{i,k} > X_{i,k'}$"? That each n-sized (vector) sample from all $N(\mu_k,\sigma)$ turns out to be ordered?

Comment: @A.S. No, I mean that $X_{i,k}$ is drawn from $N(\mu_k,\sigma)$ and similarly $X_{i,k'} \sim N(\mu_{k'},\sigma)$ and if we are given an "observation," it is in the form $X_{i,k} > X_{i,k'}$ or $X_{i,k'} > X_{i,k}$, from which we can make an inference about the values of $\mu_k$ and $\mu_{k'}$.

Comment: So observations are not $X_{i,k}$ themselves but their ordering only (for fixed $i$)? Basically you are given a ranking of $X_{i,k}$?

Comment: @A.S. Observations are orderings of $X_{i,k}$ but you are not necessarily given a complete ranking, only a partial ordering over a subset of all $X_{i,k}$ for fixed $i$.

Comment: I'm afraid that's too general of a setting that you need to restrict somehow to get a handle on. Your approach to $n=2$ doesn't seem correct either. If $\sigma=0$, $E(|X_1-X_2|)=\frac 2{\sqrt \pi}$ and it should be an increasing function of $\sigma$.

Comment: @A.S. I am mostly looking for a good resource that I can find that approaches questions very similar to this; that would certainly be the most helpful thing in the long run.

Comment: On the one hand you need to maximally specify the problem to solve it (which you haven't done), on the other hand you need to maximally generalize the actual problem you are trying to approximate (which you haven't done either). Pick which one you want to do. Is normality important? What kind of data do you actually observe? The most general answer is Bayes law: $P(\mu|Data)=\frac {P(Data|\mu)P(\mu)}{P(Data)}$ which can easily be translated into densities.

Comment: @A.S. How does one interpret $P(\mu)$ if $\mu$ is not a proposition but a random variable?

Comment: I took some liberties with notation, so that $\mu$ above means any event (related to $mu$), such as $P(\mu<t)$ or $P(\mu\in[x,x+dx])$. You can use densities ($f$) everywhere instead of $P$ and it will still work in a "random variable" interpretation of $\mu$.